# How i gonna transfer a data from listbox to textbox using index numbers?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, arraylist

This the layout I made in the VB.net :

[image]

How do I transfer one item from the listbox I made to the label box or textbox(optional) using numbers only. I created also a array for it to add to the listbox.

Here's the whole code

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim ArrayofNames() As String
    Dim x As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Retrievebtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Retrievebtn.Click
        If ListBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Retrievetextbox.Text & " " & ArrayofNames.Length - 1)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Addbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Addbtn.Click

        Dim x As Integer = 0
        ReDim ArrayofNames(x)
        For x = 0 To ArrayofNames.Length - 1
            ArrayofNames(x) = Addtextbox.Text
            ListBox1.Items.Add(ArrayofNames(x))

        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It´s unclear what you really want here. If you just want so show the selected item in the textbox you could use [DataBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding?view=net-5.0). Would be convenient to switch `ArrayofNames` into an object anyway

Comment: @AlexB. Hi. uh. It's like from the listbox there are 4 names example, John, Rick and Dominic. Then I gonna transfer one of it to the textbox with only use of array index. Is it possible?  Its like retrieving one item from the listbox to textbox. That's the instruction of my professor to the activity I'm doing at the moment. Then its kind a though for me. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Simply do `TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.Items(yourIndex).Value`.

Comment: @preciousbetine Hi. It showing an error. It says "System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'Value' on type 'String' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m not sure why your professor instructs you to use an arbitrary array but that´s another question. The following code reflects the desired behavior:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim ArrayofNames() As String

    Private Sub Retrievebtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Retrievebtn.Click
        Dim idxRetreive = Integer.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
        TextBox3.Text = ArrayofNames(idxRetreive)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        syncItemArray()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Addbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Addbtn.Click
        Dim newItem = TextBox1.Text
        ListBox1.Items.Add(newItem)
        syncItemArray()
    End Sub

    Private Sub syncItemArray()
        ReDim ArrayofNames(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
        ListBox1.Items.CopyTo(ArrayofNames, 0)
    End Sub
End Class
```