# How to transfer data from listbox to textbox in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I did some activity but I cant figure out how to retrieve data from listbox1 to textbox1. Example in the listbox1 there are 4 names: John, Jorge, Joe. Then I want to transfer Joe from listbox1 to textbox1. I did an arraylist where I adding those 3 names in the listbox1 but I didn't know how to retrieve the name "Jorge" from listbox1 to textbox1. Send help.

**Here's the code where I try to retrieve one of the name from listbox1 to textbox1**

```
Private Sub Retrievebtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Retrievebtn.Click

    If textbox1.Text = ListBox1.Items.Count Then

        textbox1.Text = ArrayofNames(x)

    End If

End Sub
```

**Here's the whole code**

Public Class Form1

```
Dim ArrayofNames() As String
Dim x As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Retrievebtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Retrievebtn.Click
    If textbox1.Text = ListBox1.Items.Count Then

        textbox1.Text = ArrayofNames(x)

    End If



End Sub

Private Sub Addbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Addbtn.Click
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    ReDim ArrayofNames(x)
    For x = 0 To ArrayofNames.Length - 1
        ArrayofNames(x) = Addtextbox.Text
        ListBox1.Items.Add(ArrayofNames(x))

    Next

End Sub

Private Sub removeBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles removeBtn.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
End Sub
```

End Class

[Here's the Image of the interface i try to retrieve the name Joe but it wasn'tshowing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCxpt.png)

Comment: Please don't post a question more than once! You already got the answer in a comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67055539/how-i-gonna-transfer-a-data-from-listbox-to-textbox-using-index-numbers?noredirect=1#comment118531107_67055539

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go over the code you posted.

In the retrieve button click event you are comparing and `Integer` to a `String` with `textbox1.Text = ListBox1.Items.Count` This won't compile with Option Strict On. You do have Option Strict On, don't you? You should always have this on.

On the next line, you assign the value of `ArrayofNames(x)`, where `x` refers to your form level variable, to a text box's Text property. Since the value of `x` is never changed anywhere in the code this will always return the 0 index in the array. (The first element) I can't imagine why it should matter that the Textbox.Text should equal the count of the ListBox items.

In the add button click event you first declare a local variable `x`. Any code in the method will use this `x`, not the form level `x`. You `ReDim` (without the `Preserve` keyword) the array to an array with a single element. Your `For` loop is silly because the length of `ArrayofNames` is 1, so it is `0 To 0`.

The `ArrayofNames` will never have more than a single element and it will be overwritten each time the add button is clicked.

Fortunately the Listbox maintains its own collection of items.

We can use this collection to simplify your code. Just add the contents of the text box to the the list items.

To retrieve a value from the list box you must first determine if the user has entered a valid index. First, is the entry a valid Integer and is it an index present in the list box.

Remember that .net collections start at index 0.

I use default names in my test program but you should continue to use meaningful names for your controls.

```
'Your add button
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim index As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, index) AndAlso index >= 0 AndAlso ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 >= index Then
        TextBox2.Text = ListBox1.Items(index).ToString
    End If
End Sub
'Your add button
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
   ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox3.Text)
End Sub
```